# Change hard coded server name in SSIS packages

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, automation

I have a conversion issue. We have approximately 100 SSIS packages that were written with a hard coded SQL server name.

We have just been informed that the server name we currently use is changing to a new name. I am trying to find out if there is any tools, apps, Powershell scripts, et cetera that can be used to make this change without having to manually open up each package and make the changes. By the way, almost all the packages are encrypted.

Comment: sure something can be written to figure it out.  But to buy yourself time if they old server is going away being retired you could cname alias that old server name to the new one and it will still wrok.

Comment: The brutal truth of this situation is that a find and replace style solution only perpetuates the problem.  The next time you need to change the connection information, you will be in the same place you are now.  This is the ideal time to upgrade to package configurations.  This will give you so much more control over development and testing -- it should be a priority anyway.

Comment: The old server is being retired, but the company has a new naming policy they adhere too, and the old name cannot remain.

Comment: I agree, what I am asking for will perpetuate the problem, I was just trying to by us some time. The correct way is to rewrite the packages to accept parameters, but that will require even more time. Was hoping this would get us converted, and than we can put a project in place to do it the right way.

Comment: Just pass in the new server name as a parameter for the ssis package and execute it using sql. it will overwrite existing name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a config file to replace the connection string?

It won't matter what the hard-coded value currently is as the config will replace it.

Personally, I develop all packages to run in DEV (with a hard-coded server/file share reference), but apply a config when running through agent. That way when you promote packages from DEV to TEST and PROD all you have to do is update the config with the new conn string and file share location.